# pgf Weird error "Missing number treated as zero"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am preparing a dissertation. I'm using Visual Studio Code and Miktex. After reading many related questions here about "Missing number, treated as zero", I still do not understand why the following example results in such an error message. I used Geobra Classic to generate this code.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39215686274509803,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
            x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-5.912600483813963,
            xmax=10.112505461619168,
            ymin=-5.0000004190058975,
            ymax=5.000000419005901,
            xtick={-5,-4,...,10},
            ytick={-5,-4,...,5},]
        \clip(-5.912600483813963,-5.0000004190058975) rectangle (10.112505461619168,5.000000419005901);
        \draw[line width=2pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.791287717641796:0.9999998864501113] plot(\x,{sqrt((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5)});
        \draw[line width=2pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=1.791293439719924:10.112505461619168] plot(\x,{sqrt((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5)});
        \draw[line width=2pt,color=ccqqqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.791287717641796:0.9999998864501113] plot(\x,{0-sqrt((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5)});
        \draw[line width=2pt,color=ccqqqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=1.791293439719924:10.112505461619168] plot(\x,{0-sqrt((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5)});
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \draw[color=qqwuqq] (-2.753604403186806,0.22489541633604176) node {$f$};
            \draw[color=ccqqqq] (-2.753604403186806,0.026150629806518583) node {$g$};
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message say:

```
<to be read again> 
                   n
l.26    \end{axis}
                
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Why am I getting the Missing number, treated as zero error?

Thanks 3000!

Comment: you get such an error if you use sqrt on a negative number. This could be due to rounding errors. You could e.g. add `abs` : `sqrt(abs(...))`

Comment: Awnsome, thank you @UlrikeFischer. I changed my funtion to ```plot(\x,{sqrt(abs((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5))}); ``` and problem solved

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved by comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, Ulrike Fischer found the answer for my question.
All I need is change my funtion to `plot(\x,{sqrt(abs((\x)^(3)-6*(\x)+5))});`